# Bitmap and image size

Tags: mysql, rest, https, bitmap

I have two ways I can store images in my database.

1. Store as bitmap in my SQL table:

```
{
name: "picture1",
ImageBitmap: "25fd73dye80942qfo2579_6306"
}
```

Or 2. store them somewhere on the server and keep the URL in the table :

```
{
name: "picture1",
ImageBitmap: "https://myserver.com/imagefolder/picture1.png"
}
```

In the first scenario, assuming I'm retrieving 100 rows and each image is like 1mb.

If I make an http request to this endpoint, would it return 100mb data? Or the size of the bitmap is not equal to the size of the image?

Comment: every thing that makes the databse big makes it also slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your "bitmaps" in your database are Base64 encoded. But that's a guess. You don't have to use  Base64 if you use [BLOB objects in place of TEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) objects.

It's hard to tell from your question whether, in the first scenario, a single request returns all the images or just one per request. But that being said, you'll have problems in production with single responses of the size on the  order of 0.1 GiB. Not a good idea. Use more requests, each returning a much smaller result.

Your first scenario is, with respect, a terrible idea. Why?

1. Every time a web browser or other client wants an image, your MySQL server will have to move a lot of data to your REST server, and the REST server will have to pass it on to your client.  That's a lot of load.  Database servers are scarce resources in scaled up systems. You don't want to burden them with all the SSD and network IO required to deliver images to clients.
2. When a client retrieves an object from a directory on a server, it makes use of a file-based web server. When that web server (apache, nginx, lighttpd) gets the request it maps the file into RAM and sends it out.  That style of server has been under development for a quarter-century now: they are efficient and secure, and easy to configure and monitor.
3. Retrieving objects that way can be scaled up to exploit a global content delivery netwwork *really* easily. (Cloudflare? Amazon Cloudfront? even Akamai if you're rich.)
4. Your image objects, served from file-based web servers, can exploit the caching aspects of the http protocol, so they won't have to be served over and over to the same client, or event to the same proxy. They're static: they don't change without their names changing.
5. Directories full of files are *much* easier to back up and restore than large database tables full of BLOBs.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question directly:

Your bitmap data is base64 encoded. The way base64 works is that three 8-bit binary bytes are encoded in four 6-bit base64 digits, so the digits can be represented by printable ASCII characters.

This means base64 encoded data is exactly 4/3 the size of equivalent binary data. It is larger than the binary data it encodes.